# Delphi Looping through TextFile for specific string the copying that string to a variable

Tags: delphi, text-files

So line containing 'NVMEM' successfully deletes from the textfile. I actually want the opposite to happen where it will delete every line apart from the line containing the string 'NVMEM'. I tried changing the if statement under button 2's for loop, to an if not statement thinking that would work but it just deletes everything. Is there a way for me to be able to delete all of the lines apart from the one containing the stringy string.

```
implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
NVE: TextFile;

begin
if not FileExists('NVE.txt') then
  begin
  AssignFile(NVE, 'NVE.txt');
  Rewrite(NVE);

  WriteLn(NVE, 'abcdefg') ;
  WriteLn(NVE, 'hijklmnop')      ;
  WriteLn(NVE, 'fmdiomfsa');
  WriteLn(NVE, 'heres the line with NVMEM'); //line I want to parse


  ShowMessage('You have successfully created the file amigo');
  CloseFile(NVE);

  end;


if FileExists('NVE.txt') then
  begin
    AssignFile(NVE,'NVE.txt');
    Rewrite(NVE);

    WriteLn(NVE, 'abcdefg') ;
    WriteLn(NVE, 'hijklmnop');
    WriteLn(NVE, 'hope i got that right');
    WriteLn(NVE, 'heres the line with NVMEM'); //line I want to parse

      ShowMessage('Eso Final');
      CloseFile(NVE);

  end;
end;

procedure TForm3.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
NVE: string;
i : integer;
raw_data1,stringy: string;
raw_data: TstringList;
begin
  stringy := 'NVMEM';
  i := 0;
  raw_data := TStringlist.Create;
  try
    raw_data.LoadFromFile('NVE.txt');
    for i := raw_data.Count-1 downto 0 do
      if pos(stringy, raw_data[i])<>0 then
        raw_data.Delete(i);
    raw_data.SaveToFile('NVE.txt');
  finally
    raw_data.free;
  end;
end;



end.
```

Comment: There is no `if not` statement, but a `not` operator. `if not a <> 0 then` is the same thing as `if (not a) <> 0 then`, that is, this tests if the bitwise negation of `a` is non-zero. That is NOT the same thing as `if not (a <> 0) then` which tests if `a` is zero. But surely you would write that as `if a = 0 then` instead.

Comment: You probably forgot that section when you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#Operator_Precedence) earlier today!

Comment: What does `pos()` return if the searched for string is found, and if it is not found?

Comment: @JordonDraggon No need to delete questions - you can edit them. Now all previous comments are gone.

Comment: @TomBrunberg: Doesn't that require 10k rep?

Comment: @TomBrunberg: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes, you are right.

Comment: @TomBrunberg does nothing., leaves the text as it is in the text file

Comment: I didn't ask what it is doing, I asked what it returns. What I actually wanted to, was to point out the location of your error. Why would you want to delete the line that matches `stringy`? `if pos(stringy, raw_data[i])<>0` indicates a match, no?

Comment: This was the code i use previously to delete lines i didn't need out of a text file, i didn't know how to convert it to either copy or delete everything else, which is the reason for this post.

Comment: for anyone who had the same issue as me, check out this linked, this worked for me !          https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553345/delphi-copy-specific-lines-from-stringlist-to-another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First recall what `function Pos(SubStr, Str: string): integer` does.

```
`Pos()` returns the position of `SubStr` within `Str` if `SubStr` is included in `Str`.
`Pos()` returns 0 when `SubStr` is not included in `Str`.
```

Now, to these lines of code in `Button2Click()` (where `i` is the index of a line in `raw_data`) that you want to modify to delete all lines except the one that contains "NVMEM":

```
  if pos(stringy, raw_data[i]) <> 0 then  // your current code
    raw_data.Delete(i);
```

Which can be spelled out as "if stringy is included in raw_data[i], then delete raw_data[i]" and which is opposite of what you want.

To turn the logic around, that is, "if stringy is **not** included in raw_data[i], then delete raw_data[i]", do as follows:

`Pos()` returns 0 when `SubStr` is not included in `Str`, ergo, the condition for deleting a row should be:

```
  if pos(stringy, raw_data[i]) = 0 then   // change `<>` to `=`
    raw_data.Delete(i);
```

That will leave you with one line left in the `raw_data: TStringList`, the line that contains "NVMEM"